# Error while trying to publish MVC app to IIS on Windows server using Web Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, iis, model-view-controller, webdeploy

I am trying to publish my MVC app to my IIS server running on windows server from Visual Studio but it keeps saying server not found error below even though am able to ping the server and get a response.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("servername"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)  WebPortal       0
```

Comment: Computer networking 101: ping/ICMP only indicates a machine is available in network layer, but Web Deploy publishing requires the server to be reachable in application layer as it uses a special protocol. The error message already contains a guide on how to resolve the issue, https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can slove this issue by deleting all the web deploy folders in program files(x86)\IIS and in Program Files\IIS, and the link provided in the error message may also help you.